# How to return a substring between two matching substrings in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string

I am brand new to programming and just getting started in an online program. The problem I am being presented with is:
Return a substring between two matching substrings.
The string I'm using is:
"Violets are blue, the sky is really blue"

I am trying to produce the substring between the two "blue"s.
That is:

```
", the sky is really "
```

This was one of my attempts which doesn't work. I was trying to slice it using `indexOf()` and `lastIndexOf()`.

```
module.exports.substringBetweenMatches = function(text, searchString) {

  return text.substring(function indexOf(searchString), function lastIndexOf(searchString);

};

module.exports.substringBetweenMatches("Violets are blue, the sky is really blue", "blue");
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty much the idea. I might have messed up the syntax for JavaScript in some places, but the logic is such:

```
function endsWith(a, s) {
  var does_it_match = true;
  var start_length = a.length()-s.length()-1;
  for (int i=0; i<s.length(); i++) {
    if (a[start_length+i]!=s.charAt(i)) {
        does_it_match = false;
    }
  }
  return does_it_match;
}

var buffer = new Array();
var return_string = "";
var read = false;
for (int i=0; i<string1.length(); i++) {
    buffer.push(string1.charAt(1));
    if (endsWith(buffer, "blue") && read==false) {
        buffer = new Array();
        read = true;
    }
    else if(endsWith(buffer, "blue") && read==true) {
        break;
    }
    if (read==true) {
        return_string = return_string.concat(string1.charAt(i));
    }
}

return return_string;
```

Comment: I don't think that will pass the mocha tests. This is a string lesson. The instructions say - Complete the `substringBetweenMatches` function. This function should:
    - Take two strings as arguments. The first string is the one to search, the second is the one to search for
    - Return the substring between the first match and the last match
    - Not include the first match or the last match in the returned substring

Answer (score 0):

If the string will potentially have more than 2 "matches", you could split the string on the matches, then loop through and concat the strings back together:

```
var array = text.split(searchString); // split the given text, on the search term/phrase

if (array.length > 2) { // check to see if there were multiple sub-sections made
    var string = ""; 
    for (var i = 1; i < array.length; i++) { // start at 1, so we don't take whatever was before the first search term
        string += array[i]; // add each piece of the array back into 1 string
    }

    return string;
}

return array[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have stumbled upon this problem myself as a student on the Bloc.io bootcamp program. I stuck to the lessons string.substring() method and also string.indexOf() methods. Here is my go at this answer.

```
substringBetweenMatches = function(text, searchString) { //where text is your full text string and searchString is the portion you are trying to find.
  var beginning = text.indexOf(searchString)+searchString.length; // this is the first searchString index location - the searchString length;

  var ending = text.lastIndexOf(searchString); // this is the end index position in the string where searchString is also found.

  return(text.substring(beginning,ending)); // the substring method here will cut out the text that doesn't belong based on our beginning and ending values.
};
```

If you are confused by my code, try:
 `console.log(beginning);`
 and 

`console.log(ending);`

to see their values and how they would work with the substring() method.

Here is great reference to the substring() method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring

Here is a JS Fiddle test. I use alert() instead of return. The concept is similar. https://jsfiddle.net/felicedeNigris/7nuhujx6/

I hope that is clear enough with my long comments on the sides?

Hope this helps.